# Use IF condition inside where clause in MYSQL and group by clause

Tags: mysql, if-statement, join, group-by, where-clause

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=19282fa4d0f99337f945c968be523a0e)

In the table in above link, the `balance_aftermonths` holds the remaining balance after each month.
For current year, I want to check the remaining balance after each month in current year , which I calculate using :

```
where MONTH(monthlydates) = MONTH(curdate())
```

However, for the older dates (for example 2019 in example), the  total remaining balance should not be current month but the last month in the contract, something like this:

```
WHERE YEAR(monthlydates) = YEAR(end_date) AND MONTH(monthlydates) = MONTH(end_date)
```

QUESTION: My question is that, how these two can be accommodated in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if i understand well
try this query

```
    (select contract_prod , start_date , end_date, MONTH(curdate()) as checkedmonth , 'curdate' as method , sum(balance_aftermonth) 
from contracts_balance 
 where MONTH(monthlydates) = MONTH(curdate()) AND YEAR(monthlydates) = YEAR(curdate())
 group by contract_prod, start_date,end_date )
union all
(select contract_prod , start_date , end_date, MONTH(end_date) as checkedmonth , 'end_date' as method , sum(balance_aftermonth) 
from contracts_balance 
 where YEAR(monthlydates) = YEAR(end_date) AND MONTH(monthlydates) = MONTH(end_date) AND YEAR(monthlydates) != YEAR(curdate())
group by contract_prod, start_date,end_date )
```